# Error: android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Tags: android

My app is published on GooglePlay. In the reports, I see such an error in android 11. Unfortunately, the app does not have third-party analytics built in and I cannot see the details of this error. I also cannot reproduce this error on my device. Do you have any thoughts? Kotlin, targetSDK 30.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3792)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3968)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2307)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8512)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: which version have you used of targetSDK version..?

Comment: I use targetSDK 30 in the project